# how to inject maven profile's properties in application.properties with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, properties-file

I defined three profiles in my pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>

        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>development</activatedProperties>
            <env.identifier>dev</env.identifier>

        </properties>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>qualification</id>

        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>qualification</activatedProperties>
            <env.identifier>klif</env.identifier>

        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>production</id>

        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>production</activatedProperties>
            <env.identifier>prod</env.identifier>

        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I also modified my build node to this :

```
<build>
    <finalName>myApplication</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And i created three properties files and as a name this pattern : application-[profileId].properties.
In the application.properties which is the general one I defined the property :

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

to specify to spring boot which profile to use.
I also defined a file for my log files as followed :

```
logging.file=logs/facade_@env.identifier@.log
```

The problem is that when I launch my application even when specifying the profile I always get as a value for my env.identifier dev.
How to resolve this problem? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this. Don't use maven profiles to create multiple artifacts. This basically means you are going to production with an untested artifact. Just specify those parameters when starting the application for the different environments instead of trying to use maven profiles for that.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

You might be missing maven resource plugin:

```
<plugins>


      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
         <configuration>
           <delimiters>
             <delimiter>@</delimiter>
           </delimiters>
           <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
```

Then in your command you just have to add:

```
mvn resources:resources
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this plugin do?

Comment: You can go here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/. I always used it in conjucntion with the <filtering>true</filtering> on certain resources which you already have specified. In your properties file i think you have ${env.properties} instead of @env.properties@. Give it a try

Comment: Well it's not working unfortunately. The syntax @env.properties@ is the new one from spring boot. It doesn't recognize the ${} anymore

Comment: Still nothing. In fact seems like spring boot can't inject anything from the pom.xml :/ I don't know what i'm doing wrong ...

Comment: normally i just generate my jar and launch it i do something like : mvn clean package and then i run my application using java -jar application.jar -D profileName. I also tried your resources:resources but doesn't give what we expected

Comment: where exactly do you hold those properties files.. and what is the version of your spring boot

Comment: The properties files are in src/main/resources and the version of spring boot is : 1.4.2RELEASE.